# What does a select statement inside a select statement mean?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

What does a Transact SQL statement `Select` statement inside a `from` mean?

I mean something like this

```
 .. from ( 
    select .. 
 )
```

Also, I need to know if the statement is bad for performance.  Can you provide me a link to the official documentation about this topic in Transact SQL?

Comment: sometimes called a nested SELECT, or a subquery, or possibly a temp table, or even inline view.  if you post your entire query, you will likely be able to get help with a version that uses more normal joins.

Comment: "Official" documentation: [Subquery Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575.aspx). You'll often run into performance issues when you deal with [Correlated Subqueries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638.aspx).

Comment: The example given in the question is actually a "derived table", not a sub-query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are talking about `subquery`. A subquery is used to return data that will be used in the main query as a condition to further restrict the data to be retrieved.

Please refer this link:- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm

Answer (score 3):

See [this link on MSDN about Subquery Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Subqueries can be fine, but be warned that they are not indexed.  If the outer part of the query must join to the results of the subquery, performance will likely suffer.  Note that the query optimizer may also choose a different execution order for your query, so even if you "start from" a subquery, the optimizer may start the query somewhere else and join to your subquery.

[Correlated Subqueries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187638.aspx) (Joe Stefanelli linked here first in the comments above) are another performance problem.  Any time you have a query that must be run repeatedly for the results of an outer query, performance will suffer.

See this [link about Common Table Expressions (CTEs)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx). CTEs may be a better way to write your query.  Other alternatives to subqueries include [@table variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) and [#temporary tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx).

One of the most common uses of subqueries is when updating a table.  You cannot have an aggregate function in the SET list of an `UPDATE` statement.  You have to calculate the aggregate in a subquery, then join back to the main query to update the table.  For example:

```
-- A table of state and the total sales per state
declare @States table
(
    ID varchar(2) primary key,
    totalSales decimal(10,2)
)

-- Individual sales per state
declare @Sales table
(
    salesKey int identity(1,1) primary key,
    stateID varchar(2),
    sales decimal(10,2)
)

-- Generate test data with no sales totalled
insert into @States (ID, totalSales)
select 'CA', 0
union select 'NY', 0

-- Test sales
insert into @Sales (stateID, sales)
select 'CA', 5000
union select 'NY', 5500

-- This query will cause an error: 
-- Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
-- An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.
update @States
set totalSales = SUM(sales)
from @States
inner join @Sales on stateID = ID

-- This query will succeed, because the subquery performs the aggregate
update @States
set totalSales = sumOfSales
from
(
    select stateID, SUM(sales) as sumOfSales
    from @Sales
    group by stateID
) salesSubQuery
inner join @States on ID = stateID

select * from @States
```

Comment: ok can you provide an examples of good and bad uses of subqueries ?

Answer (score 0):

You'll find lots of information on this with a quick search. For example, see 
[Subquery Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189575.aspx) from MSDN

> A subquery is a query that is nested inside a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE,
>   or DELETE statement, or inside another subquery. A subquery can be
>   used anywhere an expression is allowed.